# Turing machine that can move right only $O(1)$ steps beyond input

Tags: turing-machines, turing-completeness

I need to prove that a Turing machine that can move only $k$ steps on the tape after the last latter of the input word is not equal to a normal Turning machine.

My idea is that given a finite input with a finite alphabet the limited machine can write only a finite number of "outputs" on the tape while a normal Turing machine has infinite tape so it can write infinite "outputs" but I have no idea how to make it into a formal proof.

Comment: Cf. [Turing machine with a finite tape after the input word ends](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/126097).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your machine uses $n + k = O(n)$ space. As such, it can be simulated by a [linear bounded automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton). The latter is known to be weaker than a general Turing machine. For example, it cannot solve the halting problem for machines using $n^2$ space, a problem that Turing machines are able to solve.